# Registering Log4Net Named Logger with Autofac next to Log4Net Module

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, autofac

Currently I am using the Log4Net module to register my logger instances using AutoFac:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new Log4NetModule());
```

This works just fine, however, now I need to be able to write certain logging lines to a separate file. Obviously I would like this to be injectable so I thought of doing it as follows:

Interface:

```
public interface IStatisticsLogger : ILog
{ }
```

Autofac Registration:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(LogManager.GetLogger("Statistics"))
   .As<IStatisticsLogger>();
```

Log4Net config:

```xml
<logger name="Statistics" additivity="false">
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="StatisticsFileAppender" />
</logger>

<appender name="StatisticsFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs\Statistics.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1000KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date,%message%newline" />
      </layout>
</appender>
```

Class:

```
public Service(ILog logging, IStatisticsLogger statisticsLogger)
{
   // logging = General logging
   // statisticsLogger = Log to a specific file
   ...
}
```

However, when I run this I receive the following error:

The type  `log4net.Core.LogImpl` is not assignable to service `IStatisticsLogger`.

Any ideas on how I can get achieve my goal?

Comment: Assuming AutoFac supports interfaces as instances, you can cast your instance, i.e. `.RegisterInstance((ILog)LogManager.GetLogger("Statistics"))`

Comment: GetLogger() already returns ILog, so casting does not do anything

Comment: The reason I suggested it was that I noticed that the error message referenced `log4net.Core.LogImpl` which is the default implementation of ILog, as returned by GetLogger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing

```
containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(LogManager.GetLogger("Statistics"))
                .As<IStatisticsLogger>();
```

you are telling *Autofac* to cast the return of `LogManager.GetLogger("Statistics")` which is a `ILog` to a `IStatisticsLogger`. This is not valid because an `ILog` is not a `IStatisticsLogger`.

In order to use the `IStatisticsLogger` interface, you should have an implementation of such interface.

```
public class StatisticsLogger : IStatisticsLogger 
{
    public StatisticsLogger(ILog logger)
    {
            this._logger =  logger; 
    }
    private readonly ILog _logger; 

    // implements ILog 
    public virtual void Info(Object message)
    {
        this._logger.info(message); 
    }

    // etc. 
}
```

Then, you will be able to register this type in *Autofac* :

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<StatisticsLogger>()
                .WithParameter("logger", LogManager.GetLogger("Statistics"))
                .As<IStatisticsLogger>();
```

Implementing `ILog` is quite boring. You can rely on the default implementation of *log4net*.

```
public class StatisticsLogger : LogImpl, IStatisticsLogger
{
    public StatisticsLogger(ILogger logger) : base(logger)
    { }
}
```

and registration will be like this :

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<StatisticsLogger>()
                .WithParameter("logger", LogManager.GetLogger("Statistics").Logger)
                .As<IStatisticsLogger>();
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the detailed explanation.